# UITextField no callback when autocorrect changes text

Tags: ios, uitextfield, autocorrect

I added a target with editingChanged to the `UITextField` like this:

```
 self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textChanged), for: .editingChanged)
```

But if you are typing and iOS suggests the autocorrect and you tap next to where you are typing in the `UITextField`, the suggestion gets placed into the `UITextField`, but I did not get notified by the `editingChanged`.

I had the same problem with the `UITextView` and managed to "fix" it by setting the delegate and overriding

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
```

So I tried doing the same with the `UITextField` and expected to get the same result. So I set the delegate and override

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

However, still no callback when the autocorrect gets applied.

As an example, this is the autocorrect I'm talking about: [image: https://s4827.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/autocorrect_patent.jpg]

If you click on the field next to the word you're typing right now, the autocorrect gets applied. But no callback.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

---

For anybody looking for a solution here. I don't have a solution. I kept the editingChanged and added editingDidEnd. And made sure I always called self.view.endEditing(true) before I accessed the data. Not the best solution, but for now the only one I got.

Comment: I've never noticed that autocorrection anywhere. How did you get that? It probably handles setting the text field's `text` value by itself.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri It looks a little different on a real phone (I've also tested this on a real phone). It looks like half transparent blue. But you can find the option in Settings > General > Keyboards > Autocorrect. If you turn it on you will get this autocorrection. It's an iOS setting and really nothing I can change about it.

Comment: Btw, this is autocomplete and not autocorrect. Autocorrect is when you type a word wrong and tap _enter_ or _space_ and the word gets corrected.

Comment: I just tried it and my selector got triggered when i clicked on the prompted balloon text. Works fine for me on Xcode 11 beta 7.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri What you are explaining is what is happening, but it can also be triggered by clicking on another part in the UITextField. So this is autocorrect. You have to click on the empty part of the UITextField or on another word inside the UITextField. This causes the correction to be put in the UITextField, but doesn't trigger the selector.

Comment: Ah yes. You are right. But it did trigger my selector in this case as well. Just tried that specific case as well.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Really? I have tried this on a real device (iPhone 6 with iOS 12.1.3) and a Simulator (iPhone Xr with iOS 12.4) and on both I didn't receive a callback. To give some extra info: I add all views programmatically and added the target programmatically as well. Also the UITextField is inside a UIStackView which is inside a UIScrollView. I don't know if that could make a difference, but it's weird that it is working with you.

Comment: I just added a `UITextField` plainly on a view in a viewcontroller. Everything programmatically. Works fine on my 7 Plus. Xcode 11 beta 7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199183/discussion-between-kevin-van-mierlo-and-rakesha-shastri).